# Android NumberPicker has excessively large padding on the top and the bottom

Tags: java, android, numberpicker

I'm working on an Android app that has a form creator built in. I have an add- numberPicker option. The `NumberPicker` is added to a TableRow View, which is added to a TableLayout view. I want the `NumberPicker` to line up with the `EditText` next to it but the padding on the top and the bottom offsets it. The `Button` is added programmatically with this code:

```
// Add number chooser   
NumberPicker numberChooser = new NumberPicker(this);
numberChooser.setId(id);
numberChooser.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
numberChooser.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
numberChooser.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
numberChooser.setEnabled(false);
tableRow.addView(numberChooser);
```

Here is the image of the result: (the element has a black background, I want to crop of the black strips above and below the blue lines)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's probably much easier to use a plain `EditText` with `android:inputType="number"`

Comment: @techguy9984 see my answer below.